# App icons and images are not displaying in ios5

Tags: iphone, icons, ios5

After updation to ios5, all the tabbar icons and navigation images are not loading into iphone..I don't know wht the reason behing it?

Is there anything special with ios5 or I have to add images anywhere in my app?

Comment: how did you add them?.. Interface Builder? do you use own files or standard icons (via OS identifier)?

Comment: Actually i was developing app in ios4 and xcode4 But now updating to ios5 and xocde 4.2 creating the problem..

Comment: Yes but what technique do you use for setting the images?..

Comment: I directly drag them to folders in app and copy them..

Comment: and how do you use them?.. (Interface Builder, code)

Comment: As long as you don't provide a detailed description (code, image naming, directory structure) nobody will be able to help you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4437/discussion-between-gopesh-gupta-and-martin-ullrich)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in iOS 5 `drawRect:` is not on some objects e.g. `UINavigationBar`.  You have to conditionally use the new iOS 5 styling methods under these circumstances.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283534/custom-background-image-on-uitoolbar-in-ios5-sdk) question might be useful for you.